The Clock Tower Enigma
In a small, mysterious town stands an ancient clock tower that has puzzled the townsfolk for centuries. The clock doesn’t tell time as expected—it follows an unusual pattern that nobody has been able to decipher. Legend has it that if you can solve the mystery of the clock, it will reveal the location of a hidden treasure buried somewhere in the town.
The clock has four hands: Hour, Minute, Second, and a fourth mysterious hand called the "Shadow Hand," which moves differently from the others.
One day, you find a note inside the clock tower. It reads:

To unlock the treasure's might, Find the time when day turns night.
The Shadow Hand will point the way, When numbers blend at end of day.
The hour of dusk, the minute of light, The second of shadow, all must
be right. But heed the Shadow Hand, for it speaks true, Its number
hides what you must pursue.

You observe the clock at different times of the day, but it’s always shifting, except at exactly one moment when all hands align with the Shadow Hand, revealing a specific number.

So here's a first observation : Nyy guerr unaqf bs n fgnaqneq pybpx pbvapvqr rknpgyl gjb gvzrf, ng zvqavtug naq abba.

@YuzurihaInori Good observation

Is the lateral-thinking tag suitable for this question?

@Nautilus yes, my bad for forgetting the tag

In a regular clock

 the hour hand and minute hand point in the same direction 11 times every 12 hours. 10 out of 11 of those times the second hand does not align with them. But when the clock strikes 12, all 3 of them align. But neither noon nor midnight is when "when day turns night".

There is another

 way hands can align and that is when they point in the opposite direction. The hour hand and minute hand ("The hour of dusk, the minute of light") do that 11 times every 12 hours. The only time the second hand aligns with them is when the clock strikes 6 which also roughly corresponds to sunset and sunrise.


You're close, but you're missing a clue that doesn't fit with your solution.

There are multiple possible ways this can work, so there's no clear-cut solution, but one could be this:

 Assuming all the hands except the Shadow Hand work normally, they'll overlap every $720/11$ minutes. One of these overlaps with the moment when the sun sets (turning "day" into night).  But will this apply every day? We can assume that the treasure's position stays the same all the time even though the time of dusk can change throughout the year, so then these rules can only work if the sun can only set at a certain time where the clock is.  We know that on the Poles, the sun never sets for 6 months and never rises during the other 6. So you must be on the last day of the 6-month "summer" to see the Shadow Hand, and it's always the same day in the calendar. You might assume that the exact time in hours, minutes and seconds corresponds to the longitude of the treasure ("The hour of dusk, the minute of light, The second of shadow, all must be right." can have a double meaning in that they're all the overlap time's hour, minute and seconds, and it might refer to it being the same where the treasure is, hence the same latitude).


The Shadow Hand is

 the shadow cast by a spike in the center of the clock face.
 The clock must face south, so the shadow cast from this point will move anti-clockwise (different to the other three hands).
 If it faced east or west, the shadow wouldn't be visible at sunset (either because the the sun points straight at it, or because it's shaded by the tower), and if it faced north, the shadow would move clockwise.

The clock doesn’t tell time as expected

 Rather than the hands meeting twice a day at 12, they instead meet twice a day at the 3 o'clock position
 However, the clock's time is also offset by three hours, so they meet at 6am and 6pm.
 At 6pm, the shadow cast by the center spike is also going to be pointing towards the 3, causing all 4 hands to line up.

So the treasure is

 behind the number 3 of the clock?

